# Is it correct to say "I was able to enjoy the experience vicariously thru skype," rather than saying virtually

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "I was able to  enjoy the experience vicariously thru skype," rather than saying "I enjoyed it virtually thru skype."

Comment: What do you think? What is the definition of *vicariously*, and do you think it fits your meaning? What exactly is your meaning? Btw: it's *through*, not *thru*.

Comment: It could be correct, based on what you mean to say.

Comment: I wouldn't use it in that context; it's usually used to refer to being joyful because someone else you know is having fun.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

Mind you, *all* virtual communications are vicarious, whereas vicarious communications can occur without need for digital technology.

***Vicariously*** - "...by substitution of one thing or person for another; by means of a substitute. At second hand, at one remove. (OED)

***Virtually*** - "...by means of computerised simulation". (OED)